# How to add box shadow around psedo elements of polygon?

Tags: css

I added box shadows to the main shape but I can't get it to properply add to the ::before and :after triangles making up the polygon.

When I try to add `box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px #303030;` to the form `::before` and `::after` it gives a shadow around the box containing the pesduo elements

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/coolblow/pen/WyqjRx)**

```css
* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 header {
     height: 100px;
     text-align:center;
     line-height: 100px;
     background-color: gold;
}
 form {
     box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px #303030;
     background-color: lightgreen;
     margin: -10px auto;
     padding: 20px;
     width: 240px;
     position: relative;
}
 form::before {
     content: '';
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-left: 20px solid transparent;
     border-right: 20px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 20px solid lightgreen;
     position: absolute;
     top: -20px;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -20px;
}
 form::after {
     content: '';
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-left: 120px solid transparent;
     border-right: 120px solid transparent;
     border-top: 70px solid lightgreen;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: -70px;
     left: 0;
}
 input {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try maybe it will good for you -

```
<header>Header</header>
<form>
  <label for="lastname">Lastname: </label>
  <input type="text" id="lastname" />
  <br><br>
  <label for="firstname">Firstname: </label>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 header {
     height: 100px;
     text-align:center;
     line-height: 100px;
     background-color: gold;
}
 form {
     box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px #303030;
     background-color: lightgreen;
     margin: -10px auto;
     padding: 20px;
     width: 240px;
     position: relative;
}
 form::before {     
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 1px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;
    border: 20px solid black;
    border-color: lightgreen lightgreen transparent transparent;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    box-shadow: 3px -3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
 form::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    bottom: -170px;
    left: 0;

    border: 85px solid black;
    border-color: transparent transparent lightgreen lightgreen;

    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);

    box-shadow: -3px 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
 input {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
}
```

Link to jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/oj26aLmr/1/